# Null pointer exception while checking if a string is present in a string array in android?

Tags: java, android

I have an application which requires to check if a String is present in an array of String type, before adding it so as to avoid duplication. To do this, I wrote the following function:

```
public boolean arrayHas(String[] arr, String str)
{
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i].equals(str))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

To invoke this function, I'm using:

```
if(!arrayHas(contacts,str))
{
    contacts[i] = str;
    i++;
}
```

contacts and str are declared as follows

```
public static  String contacts[] = new String[]{};
String str = "";
Bundle bun = getIntent().getExtras();
str = bun.getString("key");
```

Elements are added to 'contacts' only through the main code, it is empty at the beginning. I tried adding a toast to display the value of 'str' received through the intent and it works fine. But I'm getting a NullPointerException in the 'if' statement in the arrayHas function. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Have you initialized your array elements? Most probably this is the reason.

Comment: NPE shows presence of a null pointer somewhere, can easily be found using a debugger. (?)

Comment: I tried initializing the array, didn't work!

Comment: @AbishekRamasubramaniancan you post the code for initialization bcoz nothing seems wrong here

Comment: Initializing array in the sense, fill it with strings. And also, you haven't initialized your `String str;`. Or you have skipped that code?

Comment: I've added the code for initialization too. Could you tell me what is wrong now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you haven't initialized the array with elements. So all of them are NULL.

In you arrayHas function check if the element you are comparing with is a null or not.

```
if(arr[i] != null && arr[i].equals(str) )
{
    // do your operation
}
```

Also before calling arrayHas function in

```
if(arrayHas(contacts,str)) { }
```

put a check if contacts is null or not.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

**First**: add a null check in `if` as:

```
      if(arr[i] != null && arr[i].equals(str))
```

because that position may not have assigned with a valid string yet e.g. in the `very beginning`, no assignment is made and `arr[0]` is `null` so comparison will result into `NullPointerException`.

**Second**: I think you want to check the `not ie. ! condition` in this check:

```
   if(!arrayHas(contacts,str))
   {
     contacts[i] = str;
     i++;
   }
```

Comment: and can keep the index number that show at which index last string is added, to avoid unnecessary iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid duplication, use a `java.util.Set<String>`, it will take care of it for you. You can always uso `toArray()` if you really need an array later on.

If you care about the order of your elements, you can also use a `java.util.List`, and check the presence of the element with `list.contains(str)`

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead :

```
String contacts[] = new String[10];
String str = "somethiung";
if(Arrays.asList(contacts).contains(str))
{
    contacts[i] = str;
    i++;
}
```

`Arrays.asList(.).contains(.)` gives you a much better way to test if a string is present in an array.

By the way make sure that contacts and str are properly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion to code style. Try to defensive programming., ie. you are checking whether the string `str` is present in `arr` in that case always do the check in reverse ie., `str.equals(arr[i])`, so that unnecessary `NPE`s wont be raised.

In this case an NPE could be raised at 2 points, if `arr` is null `.length and .equals` will  throw NPE's. From this its evident that, either `arr is null` , or `arr[i] is null`.

Find the method where `arr` is filled with data, there something is going wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must not have initialized your contacts[] but it might be the case like str[0]=null but str[1]="something";

in that case change

```
arr[i].equals(str) to `str.equals(arr[i])` as str is less likely to be null
```

Answer (score 0):

**-** I think you are trying to find whether a String is a present in the Array of Not.

**-** First use `Collections` cause that will be much **more flexible** in comparision to Array.

**-** Use `Collections.contains()` method to find the **String if present of not.**

**For example if you are using** `List`:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.contains("string_to_be_found");
```